# Select multiple fields, and count only one

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I want to count the **ugyfel_email** field in this select.

If i run it, i didnt get errors, but from the table records, it will only show one row.

What am i doing wrong?

```
SELECT  id,ugyfel_nev,ugyfel_email,parkolo_tipus,ugyfel_tel,rendszam,erkezes_datum,

        erkezes_ideje,allapot, utasok, COUNT(ugyfel_nev) AS ennyiszer FROM foglalas WHERE allapot = 'Feldolgozva' ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Your aggregate function make no sense due to you didn't write `group by`

Answer (score 0):

In order to count a column, you need to reference it to some other column. By that I mean it needs to represent something. In your query I assume you want to count how many **ugyfel_emain** there is for a specific allpot, this will look like:

```
SELECT COUNT(ugyfel_nev), COUNT(ugyfel_email)
FROM foglalas 
GROUP BY allapot
HAVING allapot = 'Feldolgozva' # if you want only for this
ORDER BY id DESC
```